# Python: Index not increasing in for-loop

Tags: python

trying to loop through a column in a df and if there is a NaN in the i'th cell value, I want to replace that NaN with the j'th element in list 'l'.

So when j=0 and we initiate the loop, and at i=12, there is a NaN, this NaN is replaced with l1[0]. Next round j=1, at i = 21 is the next NaN in the column, we replace this by l[1] and so on.

I tried to print the i and j indexes, but it never goes to the next j index, so it replaces all the NaNs in the column with element l[0]. So j is not increasing every time a NaN value is replaced with the j in question.

Any thoughts?
Appreciate the help!

```
l = [i for i in range(0,11)]
data = {'column': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 11,12,13]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for j in range(len(l)):
    for i in range(len(df["column"])):
            if pd.isnull(df["column"].iloc[i]):
                df.at[i,"column"] = l[j]
                print(f"i, j = {i, j}")
```

Every round I print I see i increasing but j equals 0. Note: the column length is larger than the length of the list I created.

Comment: Is it intentional that you define l above and then use l1 later? If so: Please give us a minimal working example that we can use to test (i.e. include l1 and df)

Comment: It looks like all the NaNs in `df["column_name"]` are replaced in the first iteration of the `for` loop, so there's nothing for further iterations of the `for` loop to do.

Comment: I edited the example that you can test easily. So when i = 10, np.nan will be replaced with l[0], next i = 11 and this value will equal l[1], etc..

Comment: @jjramsey, do you see why that is? it should only replace the NaN at i with j and then start all over at the next i.

Comment: Yes, it starts over with the next `i`, but `i` is the *inner* loop variable. The *outer* loop variable `j` won't change until the inner loop has finished iterating, at which point the outer loop can start its next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.fillna`:

```
df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].fillna(df["column_name"].isnull().cumsum().apply(lambda x: l[x]))
```

Or with `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df["column_name"].isnull(),"column_name"] = l[:df["column_name"].isnull().sum()]
```

Comment: Oh the .fillna method worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: However, if I wanted to implement using my initial approach, do you see the problem why j is not increasing? I.e. why are the values populated at i = 12  and j = 0 and thus stopping the for-loop?